# CSS 3 filter (blur) not using transition duration

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

I found this neat technique for cross-browser blurring. But it didn't look like the transition was having an effect, so I forked it and set the transition time and blur amount way up, and sure enough it's happening instantly.

```
img.blur {
-webkit-filter: blur(30px); -moz-filter: blur(30px);
-o-filter: blur(30px); -ms-filter: blur(30px); 
filter: url(#blur); filter: blur(30px);  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
-webkit-transition: 2s -webkit-filter linear;
-moz-transition: 2s -moz-filter linear;
-o-transition: 2s -o-filter linear;
transition: 2s filter linear;
}
```

http://codepen.io/CSobol/pen/LGCiw

Does `transition: filter` not work with blur for some reason?

Comment: looks like this sample works now :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Transition has been unprefixed, but filter has not, so the transition is over-riding the webkit-transition, but then doesn't know what to do with the unprefixed filter. This amendment works:

> transition: 2s -webkit-filter linear;

Comment: Your suggestion has correctly identified the problem. However, if I append that, then the transition only works in webkit browsers, leaving FF, Opera, Safari, and IE with no animation.

Comment: Add more transitions for each pre-fixed filter... or get rid of the unprefixed transition entirely.

Comment: Yep. Worked like a charm! Thanks a ton for the second set of eyes. I noticed that's what it was doing after you mentioned it. Nice thing to keep eyes peeled for in the future.

Comment: Use the cascade and put `transition: 2s filter linear;` at top of the list of transitions.

Answer (score 22):

Did you mean like this?

```
transition: 1s filter linear;
-webkit-transition: 1s -webkit-filter linear;
-moz-transition: 1s -moz-filter linear;
-ms-transition: 1s -ms-filter linear;
-o-transition: 1s -o-filter linear;
```